# Freemarker create separate line

Tags: freemarker

I need to add a line for separate datas in my ticket. In html, we used the tag: "hr"

> qwerty
>
> ---
>
> qwerty

but, I dont know how is in freemarker. 
Do you could help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can still output HTML using FreeMarker. FreeMarker is just a template engine that outputs text. The `<hr>` tag will still work inside your FreeMarker code.

Comment: I whrite this in my code: <hr> and my printer dont print the line for separate

Answer (score 2):

You may use ${'\n'} variable within another freemarker function to create new line in specific place